# How do I invoke a function in a parallel component in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scope

I have the following component structure:

```
       <ParentComponent />
 <Child 1 />     <Child 2 />
```

Basically, the Parent component is the main wrapper for the site; It simply renders some div tags which includes a bunch of other components(Way more than these two)

Child 1 -- this component controls the layout of some grids on the site.

Child 2 -- this is actually the navbar. However, I want to have a button in the navbar to reset the layout in Child 1 - basically, reset an array by setting state an empty array. A simple function.

How do I invoke the `resetLayout` function in Child 1, from Child 2?

Sample:

```
class Index extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            layout: []
            },
        };

    render () {

        return (
            <div>
                <NavigationBar />
                <GridLayout/>
            </div>
        )

    }
}



class NavigationBar extends React.Component{



    render () {

        return (
            <div>
                <Button onClick={this.resetLayout} /> // Want to reset layout from here
            </div>
        )

    }
}


class GridLayout extends React.Component{


    resetLayout = () => {
        this.setState({
            layout: []
        });
    };

    render () {

        return (
            <div>
                // Fancy layout goes here
            </div>
        )

    }
}
```

Basically, layout is a state in `GridLayout`. How do I access the function in there, from the `NavigationBar` component?

Comment: Maybe use a ref to the layout component in `Index` to access the method and then pass it as prop to the navbar?

Comment: I was thinking along those lines, but unsure of how to do it properly.. I'll try tinkering with it. Thanks.

Comment: I'm just not sure it's optimal design wise. It might be wiser to restructure your components but I'm not sure how right now.

Comment: The way you have it, the `ParentComponent` is actually just a sibling of the other components. Though I assume it's just a typo in the example it self and not in your actual code?

Comment: It was a typo in the first example, I updated it though sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a snippet of how to execute  a function from a sibling component. The "normal" way of doing this is to create a function in the parent that calls the child function. Then pass that function to the other child:

```js
var Parent = React.createClass({
  reset: function() {
    this.refs.childTwo.resetFunction();
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ChildOne reset={this.reset} />
        <ChildTwo ref="childTwo" />
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var ChildOne = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <button onClick={this.props.reset}>Reset the text</button>;
  }
});

var ChildTwo = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {text: "Default text"};
  },
  resetFunction: function() {
    this.setState({text: "Reset!"});
  },
  render: function() {
    return <div>{this.state.text}</div>;
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, document.getElementById('myapp'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="myapp"></div>
```

Comment: Cool example, that explains it very well. Learned something new today. thank you.

Comment: No problem. Note that I used `ref` as a string instead of a function cuz lazy :) You should change that in your implementation. Read more about it [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#legacy-api-string-refs)

Answer (score 1):

You send the command up the hierarchy by

1. implementing the function in the parent component and passing it to the child,
2. calling it from the child

In your Index class:

```
resetLayout() {
    this.setState({ layout: [] });
}

// in render function
<NavigationBar resetLayout={this.resetLayout.bind(this)} />
```

In your `<NavigationBar>`'s `render()`:

```
<Button onClick={this.props.resetLayout} />
```

By passing the state of the parent to the other child, you can effectively send the message all the way over:

```
<GridLayout layout={this.state.layout} />
```

Comment: But then state is created for layout in both Index and GridLayout. That doesn't seem too good. It needs to "live" in gridlayout; there are a lot of functions using it in there, and modifying state as well(based on user input)

Comment: @cbll The layout state of `Index` ends up as a _prop_ of `GridLayout`. But `GridLayout` can keep its own state. If you implement `componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState)` you can check for `props.layout` getting changed and act accordingly.

Comment: I see. I made it with from both examples provides(by you and someone else), thank you. It's a bit tricky to understand these things :) But clearer now!

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented small working model which updates array set in layout.You can add your layout data here instead

```js
class NavigationBar extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.reset = this.reset.bind(this);
        };
      reset(){
      var t=[];
      t[0]=Math.random();
      t[1]=Math.random();
      this.props.resetLayout(t);

      }

    render () {

        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.reset}>Reset Layout</button> 
                <GridLayout/>
            </div>
        )

    }
}


class GridLayout extends React.Component{

  
    resetLayout = () => {
        this.setState({
            layout: []
        });
    };
    componentWillMount(){
      this.setState({
        layout : this.props.layout
      })
     }
     
     componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
     this.setState({
      layout : nextProps.layout
     })
     }
    render () {
    
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.layout}
            </div>
        )

    }
}

class Index extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            layout: []
            }
        };
    resetLayout(newlayout){
      this.setState((state,props)=>{
      return {
        layout : newlayout
      }
      })
      console.log('resetting the layout')
    }
    render () {

        return (
            <div>
                <NavigationBar resetLayout={this.resetLayout.bind(this)} />
                <GridLayout layout={this.state.layout} />
            </div>
        )

    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Index />,document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id='app'>

</div>
```

Comment: This moves the "logic" to the parent instead of the child. Which is a perfectly valid approach, but not what OP seem to want or asked. Cool example though.